# How do you add the word "and" before the last item in a list? and loop list to include new words

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, loops

## Things in the Kitchen

```
listToPrint = ['pots', 'pans', 'utensils', 'plates', 'cups', 'glasses']
while True:
    newWord = input("Enter a word to add to the list (press return to stop adding words) > ")
    if newWord == "0":
        break
    else:
        listToPrint.append(newWord)
```

Comment: When are you trying to add "and" to the list? Is this after all the appends have been done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose, that you want to construct a sentence with a **compound subject**(the conjunction of singular subjects) like *"Sam, Bert and I"*
Let's say, the user entered only the word *"dishes"*.
Then, we can simply construct the final sentence using the following approach(with `list.insert()` method):

```
listToPrint = ['pots', 'pans', 'utensils', 'plates', 'cups', 'glasses']
while True:
    newWord = input("Enter a word to add to the list (press '0' to stop adding words) > ")
    if newWord == "0":
        break
    else:
        listToPrint.append(newWord)

listToPrint.insert(-1, 'and')     # inserts next to last element value

print(', '.join(listToPrint[:-2]) +' '+ ' '.join(listToPrint[-2:]))
```

The output:

```
pots, pans, utensils, plates, cups, glasses and dishes
```

Comment: This list is dedicated to my parents, Ayn Rand and God

Comment: @WayneWerner, and? have they replied to your list(letter)?

Comment: Below is what my program looks like, however I'm missing a comma for the second to last word in the list.  Thanks for your help.---#listToPrint = ['pots', 'pans', 'utensils', 'plates', 'cups', 'glasses']
listToPrint = []

while True:
    newWord = input ("Enter a word to add to the list (press return to stop adding words) > ")
    if newWord == "0":
        break
    listToPrint.append(newWord)

listToPrint.insert(-1, 'and')
print(', '.join(listToPrint[:-2]) +' '+ ' '.join(listToPrint[-2:]))

Answer (score 0):

You just need to check if the current item is the last one when looping through the list.

If so, add 
`" and " + [current item]`
If not, add
`", " + [current item]` (skip comma on the first item)

Answer (score 0):

Putting `[-1]` will select the last member from the list, or the first from behind, if you will.
Also if you ment for an empty string to break out of loop you could do as i did.
Empty string returns `False`.

```
listToPrint = ['pots', 'pans', 'utensils', 'plates', 'cups', 'glasses']
while True:
    newWord = input("Enter a word to add to the list (press return to stop  adding words) > ")
    if not newWord:
        listToPrint[-1] = 'and ' + listToPrint[-1]
        break
    else:
        listToPrint.append(newWord)
```